# html/template: how to get JavaScript (JSON) escaping without <script> tag?

Tags: templates, go

The following program writes

```
<html><body>Hello <script>[{"A":"foo","B":"bar"},{"A":"bar","B":"baz"}]</script></body></html>
```

because of the `<script>`-Tag (which does some JavaScript JSON to string encoding). How can I get the same without the `<script>`-Tag?. That is: I'd like to write

```
t, err := template.New("foo").Parse("<html><body>Hello <pre>{{.}}</pre></body></html>\n")
```

and get

```
<html><body>Hello <pre>[{"A":"foo","B":"bar"},{"A":"bar","B":"baz"}]</pre></body></html>
```

back? I have seen the `| ...` syntax for contexts in the templates package, but which context should I use?

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    type keyvalue struct {
        A, B string
    }

    a := []keyvalue{{"foo", "bar"}, {"bar", "baz"}}

    t, err := template.New("foo").Parse("<html><body>Hello <script>{{.}}</script></body></html>\n")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "foo", a)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Background: I need to generate an HTML attribute for the [X-Editable JavaScript library](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html), which looks like this: `source="[{value: 1, text: 'text1'}, {value: 2, text: 'text2'}, ...]"`

Comment: 2 minutes old, three views, and already a downvote without a comment. I love stackexchange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have "special needs" regarding the generated HTML you might use `text/template`.

But maybe in your case it would be better to just convert `a` to a string representation first and stuff this string into the rendering. I think this makes it much clearer what you are trying to do.

Or: Write your own filter function (see http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Funcs) which does this string processing an call your function in the template.

Comment: I have written my own function `tojson` which I use as a filter (`{{ . | tojson }}`). I already have another function, so that was quick to implement. I hoped for an even easier solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things:

- Within the template use the `js` function (easy)
- Pass the parameter as JSON string and prevent escaping by telling go that it's HTML:

Consider this:
http://play.golang.org/p/ETvuxYXR1M

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    type keyvalue struct {
        A, B string
    }

    a := []keyvalue{{"foo", "bar"}, {"bar", "baz"}}

    tjs, err := template.New("tjs").Parse("<html><body>Hello <pre>{{js .}}</pre></body></html>\n")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    tr, err := template.New("tr").Parse("<html><body>Hello <pre>{{.}}</pre></body></html>\n")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    json, _ := json.MarshalIndent(a, "", " ")
    err = tr.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "tr", template.HTML(json))
    err = tjs.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "tjs", a)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<html><body>Hello <pre>[
 {
  "A": "foo",
  "B": "bar"
 },
 {
  "A": "bar",
  "B": "baz"
 }
]</pre></body></html>
<html><body>Hello <pre>[{foo bar} {bar baz}]</pre></body></html>
```

Comment: What does the second output do (the js function?) I can't notice any difference. The second is nice (I use a slightly different version - see my comment to Volker's answer). Thanks!

Comment: On a second look that "js" function doesn't actually do what you'd want:

http://golang.org/src/pkg/text/template/funcs.go#393

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure if this is what you want, but anyway:

```
package main

import (
        "html/template"
        "log"
        "os"
)

func main() {

        type keyvalue struct {
                A, B string
        }

        a := []keyvalue{{"foo", "bar"}, {"bar", "baz"}}

        t, err := template.New("foo").Parse("<html><body>Hello <pre>{{. | printf `%q` }}</pre></body></html>\n")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        err = t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "foo", a)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/bvbLZsIXhQ)

---

Output:

```
<html><body>Hello <pre>[{&#34;foo&#34; &#34;bar&#34;} {&#34;bar&#34; &#34;baz&#34;}]</pre></body></html>
```

And the <pre> fragment renders as

```
[{"foo" "bar"} {"bar" "baz"}]
```

in a browser.

Comment: Actually not quite the result I need. I need it exactly like the script-escaping: with colons and comma between the curly braces: `[{"A":"foo","B":"bar"},{"A":"bar","B":"baz"}]`